# undefined reference when applying patch file

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I am working on a project where I have to make some custom system calls by modifying the kernel files in a VM. I am trying to test that my calls work by applying a patch file to a new snapshot of a VM. However whenever I run the patch file i keep getting this error:

`` arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xa78): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_set_tag' ``
`` arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xa80): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_get_tag' ``

I checked and the calls are both in the syscall_64.tbl so I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue.

Comment: You have to show the code.

Comment: what is the nature of this patch? A binary patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after linux 4.19 ,you need to add _*64* as your syscall's head
like this
[image]